# How to update existing AzureRm virtual network using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

**Context**

I have an existing RM virtual network, and now I would like to add a new subnet using PowerShell:

```
# Create subnet config:
$besub = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $BESubName -AddressPrefix $BESubPrefix

# Get VNet
$vnet  = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroup

# Add subnet:
Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $BESubName -AddressPrefix $BESubPrefix -VirtualNetwork $vnet
```

All commands run successfully however no subnet added to my virtual network.

**What I've try so far:**

- Originally I've thought there should be a `Update-AzureRmVirtualNetwork`, but there is no such a command.
- I've also searched for New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnet, which has a -VirtualNetwork $vnet parameter with no success.

**Question**

How can I add new RM Subnet to my existing RM Virtual Network?

Comment: for my understanding, those changes are only saved on your local computer, you will need a `Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet` to save them to azure

Comment: @Kai, many thanks that would be an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.   You're creating the config but it is not getting applied.  This script below will do it for you.

```
# Get VNet
$vnet  = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroup

# Add subnet config to vnet:
Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $BESubName -AddressPrefix $BESubPrefix -VirtualNetwork $vnet 

# Apply subnet config to vnet:
Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet
```

Comment: Many thanks. I was expecting Update-AzureRmVirtualNetwork similarly as Update-AzureRmVM. Anyway I got error: "Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork : Subnet 'Backend' is not valid in virtual network MyVMName" where Backend is $BESubName and MyVMName is $VNetName...

Comment: What is your virtual network address prefix?  Also, what is the subnet address prefix?  Perhaps you have a conflict with your address ranges.